# Apply attribute of child to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, jquery-selectors

I'm new to JS/jQuery so any help is appreciated!:

For each anchor that has the *property* attribute, I need to get the src of its child img and apply that value as the href of the parent anchor

So for example:

```
<a property="1">
    <img src="abc.jpg">
</a>

<a property="2">
    <img src="def.jpg">
</a>

<a property="3">
    <img src="ghi.jpg">
</a>
```

would become:

```
<a href="abc.jpg" property="1">
    <img src="abc.jpg">
</a>

<a href="def.jpg" property="2">
    <img src="def.jpg">
</a>

<a href="ghi.jpg" property="1">
    <img src="ghi.jpg">
</a>
```

Thank You!

Comment: You might want to use `data-property=" ... "` instead of `property=" ... "` so that you can comply with `HTML` standards, just add the prefix "data-" to all your **custom** attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the code below
as short as possible.

```
$('a>img').each(function(){
    $(this).parent().attr('href',$(this).attr('src'))
});
```

this will loop on each of your image under anchor and assign its src value as href value of its parent anchor

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll(img).forEach(el => {
  el.parentNode.setAttribute('href', el.getAttribute('src'))
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it's better to include an explanation on how your code addresses the OP's issue. This way, future visitors can learn from your post, & apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. High quality, complete answers reinforce this idea, and are more likely to be upvoted. These features, plus the requirement that all posts be self-contained, are some strengths of SO as a platform that differentiates us from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```js
$("a").each(function() {
  let href = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
  $(this).attr("href", href);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a property="1">
    <img src="abc.jpg">
</a>

<a property="2">
    <img src="def.jpg">
</a>

<a property="3">
    <img src="ghi.jpg">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work, adds href only to a tag which has property

```
  $("a").each(function (index, value) {
    if ($(this).attr("property")) {
      console.log($(this).children().attr("src"));
      $(this).attr("href", $(this).children().attr("src"));
    }
  });
```